# Allocated Memory for Hashtable.put()

Tags: java, optimization

So I was reading Peter Norvig's IAQ (infrequently asked questions - [link](http://www.norvig.com/java-iaq.html)) and stumbled upon this:

> You might be surprised to find that an
>   Object takes 16 bytes, or 4 words, in
>   the Sun JDK VM. This breaks down as
>   follows: There is a two-word header,
>   where one word is a pointer to the
>   object's class, and the other points
>   to the instance variables. Even though
>   Object has no instance variables, Java
>   still allocates one word for the
>   variables. Finally, there is a
>   "handle", which is another pointer to
>   the two-word header. Sun says that
>   this extra level of indirection makes
>   garbage collection simpler. (There
>   have been high performance Lisp and
>   Smalltalk garbage collectors that do
>   not use the extra level for at least
>   15 years. I have heard but have not
>   confirmed that the Microsoft JVM does
>   not have the extra level of
>   indirection.)
>
> An empty new String() takes 40 bytes,
>   or 10 words: 3 words of pointer
>   overhead, 3 words for the instance
>   variables (the start index, end index,
>   and character array), and 4 words for
>   the empty char array. Creating a
>   substring of an existing string takes
>   "only" 6 words, because the char array
>   is shared. Putting an Integer key and
>   Integer value into a Hashtable takes
>   64 bytes (in addition to the four
>   bytes that were pre-allocated in the
>   Hashtable array): I'll let you work
>   out why.

So well I obviously tried, but I can't figure it out. In the following I only count words:
A Hashtable put creates one Hashtable$Entry: 3 (overhead) + 4 variables (3 references which I assume are 1 word + 1 int). I further assume that he means that the Integers are newly allocated (so not cached by the Integer class or already exist) which comes to 2* (3 [overhead] + 1 [1 int value]).

So in the end we end up with.. 15 words or 60bytes. So what I first thought was that the Entry as a inner class needs a reference to its outer object, but alas it's static so that doesn't make much sense (sure we have to store a pointer to the parent class, but I'd think that information is stored in the class header by the VM).

Just idle curiosity and I'm well aware that all this depends to a good bit on the actual JVM implementation (and on a 64bit version the results would be different), but still I don't like questions I can't answer :)

Edit: Just to make this a bit clearer: While I'm well aware that more compact structures can get us some performance benefits, I agree that in general worrying about a few bytes here or there is a waste of time. I surely wouldn't stop using a Hashtable just because of a few bytes overhead here or there just like I wouldn't use plain char arrays instead of Strings (or start using C). This is purely of academic interest to learn a bit more about the insides of Java/the JVM :)

Comment: The text you cite seems to be very old (since it mentions the Microsoft JVM). The implementation of Hashtable may well have been different at that time.

Comment: Yeah that could be true, I tried to find the source code of the 1.3 JDK but bugger me, that seems nearly impossible today xX

Comment: Could it be that you are calculating with 3 words, while the quote uses 4 words there?

Comment: Actually found an ancient 1.3jdk and the Entry class is identical (apart from missing generics obviously). @Paŭlo Sorry don't understand - I mean the code is open and I don't see where I missed a variable?

Comment: No, I mean that in the text you quoted it says *[...]that an Object takes 16 bytes, or 4 words*, while you are calculating with an overhead of 3 words. Sorry if I'm wrong here, I should have been in bed already some hours ago, can't think clear now.

Comment: Yeah every Object is at least 4 words large because the JVM always allocates at least 1 word for local variables (possibly to avoid having local variables of several objects starting at the same address) but that's only important if the Object doesn't have a local variable, because otherwise we can fill the space with something useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author appears to assume there is 3 Objects with 16 bytes overhead each and 2 32-bit references in the Map.Entry and 2 x 1 32-bit `int` values. This would total 64-bytes

This is flawed in that Sun/Oracle's JVM only allocates on 8-byte boundaries so that while technically an Integer occupies 20 bytes of memory, 24 bytes is used (the next multiple of 8)

Additionally many JVMs now use 64-bit references so the Map.Entry would use another 16 bytes.

This is all very inefficient, which is why you might use a class like TIntIntHashMap instead which use primitives.

However, usually it doesn't matter as memory is surprising cheap when you compare it to the cost of your time.  If you work on server applications and you cost your company about $40/hour, you need to be saving about 10 MB every minute to save as much memory as you are costing. (Ideally you need to be saving much more than this)  Saving 10 MB each and every minute is hard.

Memory is reusable, but your time isn't.

Comment: But compact structures can be *much* faster than bulky ones due to caching behavior, so if you use Java objects inside a tight loop, you're still wasting valuable time: the time you and the user spend waiting on the program to complete.

Comment: Oh I wouldn't even think about stopping using a HashMap or a String just because I could save a few bytes here or there and that although my idle time as a student is quite cheap indeed. That's only an academic interest so to speak. And yes we're ignoring allocation boundaries and 64bit since the entry is certainly a few years old. But still I don't see how we get the 64byte - at most we allocate 2 new Integers and 1 Hashtable$Entry - the Entry<K,V> next in HashTable$Entry isn't newly allocated but only a reference as I see it.

Comment: @larsmans, I agree that cache memory is a premium in performance critical systems. My impression of most systems is that they are not so finely tuned that caching effects are a major factor. I could be worng. ;)

Comment: @Voo, even if you are not being paid, your time is worth something.  maybe it not worth $40/hour, maybe its only 4 cents per hours, but thats still 10 KB per minute. You are only thinking about the fields in the objects, each object has an overhead.